# Non-JS inject of <style> tag in output html with Webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have an interesting use case, where I need a webpack build that will inject style tag in my index.html file, just like with style-loader...but directly into the HTML rather than with the js bundle.  Any idea how to do this?  Config as follows injects the style tag using javascript:

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: ''
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader', 'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
    
        include: /.*_sprite\.svg/,
    
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
                options: {
                    publicPath: '',
                }
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: './index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

extract-loader extracts the css string...but have no idea how to then input it into the html file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants an answer to this question, have found one.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: ''
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader', 'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
    
        include: /.*_sprite\.svg/,
    
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
                options: {
                    publicPath: '',
                }
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].css'
    })
  ]
}
```

In the head of ./src/index.html:

```
    <style>
        <%= compilation.assets[htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css].source()  %>
    </style>
```